# How to check if source code file confirms to given astyle rules?

Tags: svn, astyle

`astyle` modifies the file provided as an argument. I just want to check if particular file is `astyle` confirmed. If not return error in svn pre-commit hook. But `astyle` man page does not say anything about return value or about how to prevent in place formatting.

Answer (score 1):

diff original and Beautified file, `| wc -l` diff